# Use of Datadog and Webhooks to call multiple numbers

Tags: twilio, webhooks, datadog

I have my application integrated with Datadog for monitoring purpose. At the same time I want the notifications/calls to be sent to the team if any of the metric fails to achieve the desires value. I used Webhooks integration in Datadog for this purpose. In the webhooks configuration I have set the URL (Twilio request) and I do get a call on my number. Now I am looking for an scenario wherein if the user doesn't pick the call for say 30secs then try calling the second number. How do I achieve this?

Comment: This sounds tough. But Datadog monitors do have a "renotify if monitor not resolved" option that you can set so that it sends an escalation message every e.g. 10 minutes the monitor is not resolved. This could be to a separate webhook. Sound promising at all?

Comment: Setting the renotify value will trigger the notifications until monitor is resolved. But for me based on the response of the first call, i should decide whether to call a second number.

Comment: How did you manage to do this? what data are you sending to Twilio? If the number in the "to" field does not respond, the call is not being forwarded.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a find me Twimlet. Enter up to 10 numbers and a timeout between moving on to the next number. Twilio will do the rest.

https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme

Comment: How do you add the findme twimlet to the rest API?. Twilio voice api requires a "to" field and only triggers the twimlet after the "to" number answers the call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more full featured paid solution I'd recommend PagerDuty. DataDog has an integration for PagerDuty. Any monitor that gets triggered that mentions `@pagerduty-myteamname`(as example) in the monitor message will cause PagerDuty to page the on call person.  If that person does not acknowledge the page you can configure it to go through list of people to contact next until it is acknowledged by someone.